# How to use Multiple Controllers for one view angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to know if it is possible to use multiple controllers for a single url view using angluarjs, I have not been able to find much documentation on this.

What i tried:

```
$routeProvider

 .when('/a',
     {
         //HOW COULD I ADD TWO CONTROLLERS TO SAME PAGE??? THIS DOES NOT WORK
         controller: 'aCtrl' , 'a1Ctrl'
         templateUrl: 'a.html'
     })
 .when('/b',
     {
         controller: 'bCtrl' , 'b1Ctrl'
         templateUrl: 'b.html'
     })
```

Comment: You can nest controllers using ng-controller. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to call two controllers that is aCtrl and a1Ctrl for a.html(view).

Comment: You don't need to do it. Try to explain your task better.

Comment: since im having many lines of code. im trying to split my code.. in my a.html  im having menu like sales and product . for sales i want to call aCtrl.js and for product i want to cal a1Ctrl.js

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router ?

Comment: you can require another controller.